What was the name of an architectural (?) photographer, known for angled/tilted shots?
…who said that many of his photos are tilted, because it was "the most comfortable way to hold a camera for him" (very approximate quote).
I sadly can't remember his name and google is not very helpful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garry_Winogrand but I can't find the quote, specifically, so I can't post it as an answer (yet)
